# Best way to swap out content of a website based on URL

Tags: javascript

I want to create multiple versions of a javascript site and am trying to figure out what the best way to do it is. I will have about 3 versions that have the same structure but different text and assets depending on the URL.

So if people go to www.mywebsite.com displays a generic site but www.mywebsite.com/business displays different content and assets. I have heard of templating sites, is something like Thymeleaf the best way to approach this?

Comment: Well this is more of routing issue. But I am guessing you have figured it out. If so then you can append css or any resource by using jquery after checking the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use a pre-built template from sites like templated.co, save and use those files for each subdirectory of your website and add your code on top.
2. You can use a content-management-system such as wordpress.
3. You can build your own template, which are basically just html/css/javascript files that have the basic layout for your website, and you add the different content on top.

For instance, on your html file you can include the template style and the specific style for this page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/template.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/page1.css"/>
```

4. If you are talking about Javascript template frameworks which are very different, you might be looking at tools like mustache.js, angular.js, and handlebars.js

Answer (score 1):

If you just need different css, you may check the url when site is loading and then download necessary CSS depending on url.

You can check url using `window.location` properites. For example `pathname` property.

And then use some code to download suitable css. For example:

```
switch (window.location.pathname) {
   case: '/business'
     setCSS('business.css')
     break
   case: '/something'
     setCSS('something.css')
     break
   default:
     setCSS('default.css')
}

function setCSS(file){
    var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'http://website.com/css/' + file;
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Also pay attention that this code should be invoked when document loaded.
If you need also images or some custom texts which depend on the url, you may use the same approach (checking window.location.pathname) but run some special scripts for different variants.